# Java awt Graphics2D text rendering anti alias has dark outline

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage, graphics2d, text-rendering

I am rendering white text to a BufferedImage, and displaying it on a white background in order to identify why my text is not perfect. Even white text on a white background has a dark outline when AA is enabled.

Originally I believed this was due to the clear pixels having RGB values of 0, so an AA blend would result in a grey, however I have tried to flush the image with transparent white pixels and it does not fix the issue.

Please see code below, I have also tried many different combination of rendering hints.

```
    GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    BufferedImage fontImage = graphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage(width, height, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) fontImage.getGraphics();
    FontRenderContext context = graphics.getFontRenderContext();
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB);
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);

    graphics.setFont(font);

    //flush all pixels with clear white
    Color c = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0);
    graphics.setColor(c);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    graphics.setColor(Color.white);
    graphics.drawString(String.valueOf(str), 0, ascent);
```

The results -
no AA: 
[image]
with AA:
[image]

As you can see there is a clear dark outline around the white text, I would expect to see nothing at all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you comment out the setting of KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, do you see a difference in the rendered text?

Comment: Yes, the text is definitely sharper/more blocky, and actually the dark outline is worse!

Comment: On what operating system are you running?  And what graphics card or graphics adapter do you have?  If you’re on Windows, it may help to make sure you have the latest graphics driver.

Comment: I've updated the question with clearer images and AA/noAA. Running Windows 10 on Dell XPS 9550, GeForce GTX 960M and all drivers are up to date.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?  I am unable to reproduce this in Java 11.

Comment: Java 8. The way I am rendering this is slightly more complex than just awt, as it gets passed through to libgdx and rendered there, so I think the issue may be to do with the blending function in libgdx. I am skeptical though because I have many white icons with a similar smooth edge/AA applied and they render perfectly, it's only the text that has this annoying outline.

Comment: I am just using standard blending (srcAlpha, oneMinusSrcAlpha). I can get rid of the outline by using glOne, oneMinusSrcAlpha, but it looks much worse obviously because any pixel with an alpha > 0 is just opaque. I have even tried iterating the BufferedImage pixels though and ensuring all pixels have rgb of 255 and it still didn't help.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful.  It not only allows readers to reproduce your problem, but it also helps you isolate the cause.  If you write a short AWT-only program and don’t see the issue occurring, libgdx is more likely to be at fault.